# Using PythonQT: Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec

Tags: python, pythonqt

I have inherited a project. I can get it to compile but I am running into this runtime error. I have uninstalled all other versions of python on my machine except for the version that came with the application. Does anyone know why this error could be occurring?

Comment: Is that the entire error output?

Comment: There's also
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFBB45FDACE (ucrtbase.dll) in application.exe: Fatal program exit requested.